# Cast inherited type to generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have a property, as below:

```
public ITypeA<IType2> MyProperty {
   get {
      return new ImplementationA<ImplementationB>();
   }
}
```

How can I achieve this. `(new ImplementationA<ImplementationB>() as ITypeA<IType2>)` returns null, and casting is not allowed.

Comment: If `ImplementationA<ImplementationB>` implements `ITypeA<IType2>`, this works without a cast. If it doesn't implement it, this won't work even with a cast. I'm not seeing what the problem is you're really trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the generic parameter of the interface to be [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx) using the [`out` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx).

Comment: Can you please give me an example? Please note this is C# 3.5

Comment: @hungryMind - I've added a link to the MSDN doc on the `out` generic modifier to SLaks answer, it contains examples. @SLaks - Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I think generic covariance was introduced in C# 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 3.5, I think your best option is to use a wrappr:

```
class ImplementationWrapper : ITypeA<IType2>
{
    public ImplementationA<ImplementationB> MyObject { get; set; }
}

public ITypeA<IType2> MyProperty {
    get {
        return new ImplementationWrapper {
            MyObject = new ImplementationA<ImplementationB>()
        };
   }
}
```